# List all the private and public services on AWS using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I've been playing around with AWS using boto3 for a while now and interacting with multiple services such as ec2, s3, RDS etc. So, is there a way I can list all the private and public services available on an AWS account using boto3 code?

Comment: what do you mean by private and public service ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you can use -

```
service_list = boto3.Session.get_available_services()
```

from https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.get_available_services based on the Boto 3 documentation version 1.7.62

Comment: Thanks,this was the answer i was looking for.